# avoid sorting in the JSP pages

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
var sortitems = 1;

function move(fbox, tbox, all)
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < fbox.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (!all && fbox.options[i].selected && fbox.options[i].value != "")
        {
            var no = new Option();
            no.value = fbox.options[i].value;
            no.text = fbox.options[i].text;
            tbox.options[tbox.options.length] = no;
            fbox.options[i].value = "";
            fbox.options[i].text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            if (all && fbox.options[i].value != "")
            {
                var no = new Option();
                no.value = fbox.options[i].value;
                no.text = fbox.options[i].text;
                tbox.options[tbox.options.length] = no;
                fbox.options[i].value = "";
                fbox.options[i].text = "";
            }
        }
    }
    BumpUp(fbox);

    if (sortitems)
 SortD(tbox);
    checkSelectAll();
}
```

This move function is getting called after clicking on the button, then it will call the sort method where sorting is happening by alphabetically. So we dont need to sort we need to populate the data as it is from the left side box to right side box and vice versa, but sorting is happening. Please help out be here.

```
function SortD(box)
    {
        var temp_opts = new Array();
        var temp = new Object();
        for ( var i = 0; i < box.options.length; i++)
        {
            temp_opts[i] = box.options[i];
        }
        for ( var x = 0; x < temp_opts.length - 1; x++)
        {
            for ( var y = (x + 1); y < temp_opts.length; y++)
            {
                if (temp_opts[x].value > temp_opts[y].value)
                {
                    temp = temp_opts[x].text;
                    temp_opts[x].text = temp_opts[y].text;
                    temp_opts[y].text = temp;
                    temp = temp_opts[x].value;
                    temp_opts[x].value = temp_opts[y].value;
                    temp_opts[y].value = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for ( var i = 0; i < box.options.length; i++)
        {
            box.options[i].value = temp_opts[i].value;
            box.options[i].text = temp_opts[i].text;
        }
    }
```

Depends on the bumpup box function. The elements are moving from one box to another. It will replace the element with empty space and move to top and do for all the elements. Please help out me here

Thanks in advance

```
function BumpUp(box)
    {
        for ( var i = 0; i < box.options.length; i++)
        {
            if (box.options[i].value == "")
            {
                for ( var j = i; j < box.options.length - 1; j++)
                {
                    box.options[j].value = box.options[j + 1].value;
                    box.options[j].text = box.options[j + 1].text;
                }
                var ln = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ln < box.options.length)
        {
            box.options.length -= 1;
            BumpUp(box);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but it's hard to see what the issue is here.

If it is simply that *SortD(tbox)* is being called within the *move()* function, that's because
*sortitems* is set to 1 right at the top of the code. The value of *sortitems* is never changed anywhere else, so this conditional is always true and *SortD* is always called.

```
if (sortitems)
 SortD(tbox);
```